# Why does my PC's MXM slot claim to have a limited wattage and graphic capacity?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I bought an all-in-one HP PC and the motherboard has an MXM 3.0 Type A slot.
I'm looking forward into acquiring an MXM 3.0 Type A compatible graphic card, but the specs for the MXM slot are strongly limited.

I have two questions, the MXM 3.0 slot claims only to support up to 35 Watt. I've read that wattage is not a real limit. I can suppose that if I insert a 55 Watt graphic card the card will burn out. Why does this motherboard has such limited wattage capacity or is it PSU related?

The second question I have is that the MXM 3.0 slot also claims to have a "Shared memory up to 256 MB" I really quite don't get this. Does this mean that if I buy a 1GB graphic card my real limit while using my PC will be 256 MB at best?

I leave the link with the HP Tech specs so anyone can help me to pull this trough:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03305138

Comment: Wattage is a real limit! If you install a card that draws more current than the slot can supply, at best it'll fail to work, and at worst it'll damage the power supply or motherboard. As for the RAM question, what that means is that the motherboard will allocate up to 256MB of system RAM for the use of the graphics adapter. If you buy a card with 1GB of RAM, it shouldn't need to use shared system RAM at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aaron! I have a final question, I'm planning to buy a 35 Watt graphic card. "<35 Watt" is the tech spec for the MXM slot. Do you think is safe?

Comment: Can't say for sure; I'd think about checking with the manufacturer, or searching the web to see whether anyone's had success using the same hardware combination.

Comment: Glad to be of help! I've converted the comment to an answer, since it turned out to be more useful to you than I initially expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wattage is a real limit! If you install a card that draws more current than the slot can supply, at best it'll fail to work, and at worst it'll damage the power supply or motherboard. As for the RAM question, what that means is that the motherboard will allocate up to 256MB of system RAM for the use of the graphics adapter. If you buy a card with 1GB of RAM, it shouldn't need to use shared system RAM at all.